# Handle create instance promise inside find promise sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

unfortunately I can't seem to apply m understanding of promises to sequelize:
On my login/authenticate route I'm trying to store my token linked to my user in my database but i'm getting the unhandled promise reection error :
My method goes like this :

```
exports.authenticate = (req, res) => {
    const credentials = req.body;
    User.findOne({
        where : {
            email : req.body.login
        }
    })
    .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            console.log('notfound!')
            res.status(404).send("user not found");
        } else { 
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
            const token = jwt.sign({username : user.username}, secret.secret, {expiresIn : "2 days"});
            Token.create({
                code : token, 
                expired_at : sequelize.fn("DATEADD", sequelize.literal("day"), 2, sequelize.col(sequelize.fn('NOW')))
            }).then((tkn) => {
                console.log(tkn);
                res.status(200).json(tkn.toJSON());
            }).catch((e) => {
                res.status(500).json({"message": "Server Error"});
            });
            res.status(200).json({message : "ok", token : token});
        }else{
            res.status(403).send('wrong password')
        }
    }
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send('unhandled Server error');
    });
}
```

The Error message :

> (node:15798) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

I tried creating my Token outside the find block but I'm getting my token variable is undefined.
how can i go about storing my token after having created it .

Comment: you are sending response two time look after Token.create() your send response once in then and after other after catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood hat was going on,
i had my outer promise going about it's thing and sending me the response

```
res.status(200).json({message : "ok", token : token});
```

while the promise of `Toen.create` was stuck on the way i chose to add two days to the current date with sequelize.
After commenting the response I got to handle the error in the `Token.create` block

I don't think this is the best way to do it so feel free to throw your two cents.

Answer (score 0):

That's because code is sending response two times. first time it send response

```
 res.status(200).json(tkn.toJSON());
```

and after it code become stuck whenever it get another response.

```
res.status(200).json({message : "ok", token : token});
```